# Terminal doesn't close after shell runs the python script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have 2 python scripts `sc-1.py` and `sc-2.py` and shell file `test.sh`

`sc-1.py`

```
import time 

print('Script 1 started')
time.sleep(2)
print('Script 1 ended')
```

`sc-2.py`

```
import subprocess

print('Script 2 started')
subprocess.Popen(["sh", "test.sh"], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
print('Script 2 ended')
```

`test.sh`

```
py sc-1.py
```

It works but there is one problem. The command terminal doesn't end after the script is ended.
[image]

I have to use `ctrl + c` to end it.

[image]

Comment: no need to use shell=True when launching sh directly, right?

Comment: I removed that argument and tested. Still same issue

Comment: it is not running. just press enter again and you are back on shell. For example, you can try ctrl-Z to hang it up, you will see nothing happens because you are on shell already

Comment: Any code to end it instead of pressing enter ?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @BingWang so everything is fine ?

Comment: Do you *have* to use subprocess?

Comment: I just want to run shell script from one python file without the python file to wait for the other to finish. Just came to know about subprocess doing this. os.system waits for the other file to finish then ends which is something I dont want

Comment: Have you tried `os.popen`?

Comment: What is `py`? The Python executable is usually `python3` or `python`, unless you renamed it, of course.

Comment: @user1934428 even with python I get the same thing. Shell is not closing after running the script

Comment: @abd did you try Enter and did it work? If so, you are already on shell and it is ready to take another command. Other than not seeing the normal PATH$ prompt I don't think you miss anything

Comment: @BingWang yes enter works. I was just worried if it leaves python processes open. But I guess it is something visual bug.

Comment: I just see that the problem is not onlx your script, but the shell you are using to invoke the script. When I'm using bash as my **interactive** shell, I have the same problem, whether or not \n is used. If I use zsh, I have your problem only when I forget the \n. It seems that bash does not produce the required prompt in that case. If you do a `ls` instead of a plain ENTER, you will see that bash executes the ls. Nothing hangs, just the prompt is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to output a final newline in your Python programs, i.e. to write

```
print("Script 2 ended\n")
```

BTW, in order to make it work on my Platform (Cygwin, Python 3), I also had to do a `shell=False`, otherwise it would not have executed the shell script at all; but this doesn't seem to be necessary in your case.

**UPDATE** : The "solution" posted here applies only when I am running sc-2.py from a interactive zsh. If I use an interactive bash, I see the same effect as the OP mentions, and adding a \n does not help. However, the script is not hanging. It is terminated, but it just appears hanging because the shell does not display its prompt.

Comment: nope. new line just creates a new empty line.

Comment: And still hangs? This is strange. And a carriage return instead of control-C doesn't make things better either? Did you make sure that you have placed the \n in **both** of your Python programs?

Comment: yes both the scripts. The cursor just moves a line below. I have to press enter to be back on shell

Comment: @abd : I have amended my answer. Would you mind retesting your case inside zsh?